# String.Format with both args and date format

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that is used to create a text file that needs to include both a prefix to the file name and a date in the file name.

```
{0}_{0:MMddyyyy}.txt
```

Now if I call it like the following:

```
string.Format("{0}_{0:MMddyyyy}.txt", "PRE", DateTime.Now);
```

I would hope to get:

```
PRE_05172015.txt
```

But instead I get:

```
PRE_PRE.txt
```

Comment: it should be string.Format("{0}_{1:MMddyyyy}.txt", "PRE", DateTime.Now);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `1` in the second position, not `0`.

```
string.Format("{0}_{1:MMddyyyy}.txt", "PRE", DateTime.Now);
```

The number is an index into the list of arguments following the format string.

```
string.Format("{0}_{1:MMddyyyy}.txt",
    "PRE",         // 0
    DateTime.Now); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use:

```
string.Format("{0}_{1:MMddyyyy}.txt", "PRE", DateTime.Now);
```

Note that `{0}` represents a *placeholder* in the format string, to be filled by the argument list supplied to the `Format` call after the format string.

In your case `{0}` will be replaced, in every instance of its use, by the first argument after the format string: `"PRE"`, as you observe in your output.

Answer (score 0):

you are using 0 two times..replace second 0 with 1

```
string.Format("{0}_{1:MMddyyyy}.txt", "PRE", DateTime.Now);
```